# JQuery / Javascript Add "id" to a <div> where class="x"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a line of code which is...

```
<div class="x">
   xyz
</div>
```

I want to write a script to find the div where class == "x", and change it to be...

```
<div class="x" id="y">
   xyz
</div>
```

**any help is appreciated**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
// Without jquery
document.querySelector('div.x').id = 'y';

// With jquery
$('div.x').attr('id', 'y');
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't even leave the possibility that you could create two elements with the same ID ;)

```
$('#y').length || $("div.x:first").attr("id",'y');
```

Using guard to block the attribute change if exists. [With a "y"](http://jsfiddle.net/CuDrR/3/) and [without](http://jsfiddle.net/CuDrR/4/).

Comment: Good answer, but what if there is already an element with id 'y'?

Comment: Awesome, forward-thinking answer!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("div.x").attr("id",'y');
```

but be aware it will add the `id='y'` to any other div with class `x`

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

```
$(".x").attr('id', 'y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).find('.x').attr('id', 'y');
```

Because `.find()` works faster than `$('.x')`.